# Laravel Post Request

Tags: php, laravel

I have a table called Customer and with a Get Request I can already get all the Data (which I created with phpMyAdmin) on a HTML Template.
Now I want to create a new Customer with a Post Request.

This is the way I thought it would work:

In the Controller:

```
public function addNewCustomer(Request $request)
    {
        return \app\model\Customer::create($request->all());
    }
```

The route:

```
Route::post('posttest', 'CustomerController@addNewCustomer');
```

How can I create a validation for it?

Comment: and what is the problem?

Comment: That should work. Although some validation would be better.

Comment: share output for `$request->all()` and error message if you are getting any ?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to write, I want to know how to implement some Validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add validation of form like below in addNewCustomer,

```
public function addNewCustomer(Request $request)
{
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'title' => 'required|max:255',
        'body' => 'required',
    ]);
    return \app\model\Customer::create($request->all());
}
```

For more information about input validation in Laravel Please readout [Laravel Validation Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation)